# When should I use while loop and if statement?

Tags: python

I was trying out a question where you have to swap the adjacent elements in an array based on the number of swaps given. For example:

**Suppose, no of swaps = 2, and the array is [5,3,1]. Then the sorted array after two successful swaps will be [3,5,1] --> 1st swap, [3,1,5] --> 2nd swap. So sorted array is [1,3,5].**

This is my code on achieving the above result:

```
T = int(input())                 # This is the number of testcases
l = 0
for i in range(T):
    N, K = input().split()       # N is the size of array, K is the number of swaps needed to be done
    N, K = int(N), int(K)
    A = input().split(" ", N)    # A is the array of elements
    for j in range(len(A)):
        A[j] = int(A[j])

    while K != 0:
        for k in range(l+1, N):
            if A[l] > A[k]:
                A[l], A[k] = A[k], A[l]
                K -= 1
                l = 0
            else:
                l += 1
            break
    
    for j in A:
        print(j, end=" ")
    l = 0
    print()
```

At first, when I tried out `if K!=0`only 1 swap was done. Only after using `while K!=0`, the code worked perfectly. So,my question is why didn't it work for the `if` statement? When is it appropriate to use `if` and `while`?

Comment: I haven't looked at your code. I'm just reading the last paragraph. You should know yourself when you want your program to execute certain task multiple times or some task only once given a certain condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Please be aware that what you are working with are *lists*, not *arrays*, and that ``{5,3,1}`` denotes a *set*.

Comment: Are you aware what ``if`` and ``while`` do? Do you know the difference between them? How often do you think each of them will evaluate their condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` will only check the value of k once,
`while` will continue(like a loop) what in the scope till your condition is `false`
you can use `while` if you are waiting for a specific action to stop/break, and `if` when need to check something at a time.
I hope that was clear.
in your case `for` will works well.

Comment: If I use `if` you can see in the code, that after the `break` statement it will return back to the `if` clause and check whether `k is equal to 0`, then again the `for` loop will start and this will continue. Same goes for the `while` loop. So,they are both the same,aren't they?

Comment: Do you mean to use `if` instead of `while`? if that so, the break will take you out of the `for`, the `if` will be executed again

Comment: Yes, as you can see after every `break` statement the `if` would have worked. So it's the same as using `while`.  Right?

Comment: `for+if` can be the same as `while`, if you replace the 'while' in yous code with 'if' you will not have the same output

Answer (score 0):

```
  T=int(input()) 
  for _ in range(T):
                        [N,K]=list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
                        arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
                        
                        for i in range(K):
                                            arr[i],arr[i+1]=arr[i+1],arr[i]
                                           
                        print(*arr)
```

[image]

Is this what are you trying to get? Swap as you iterate through the list and stop when you have reached the swapping limit.